# Why my pc is not conecting to services? (SSL)

Tags: windows, mongodb, ssl, curl, npm

All starts one day that my pc command line programs stop working, everyone has an error related to *SSL*, for example:

- CURL: `"failed to verify the legitimacy of the server ca bundle"`
- NPM: `"UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"`
- MONGODB: `MongoError: connection 0 to xxx.mlab.com:xxx timed out`

I am using the same code with mongo on an ec2 instance working ok, but local is not, i am using:

- Windows 10
- CURL 7.58
- NPM 3.10
- NODE 6.11.2
- MONGODB 2.2.32

Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? The MongoDB driver does not emit any message containing `CURL` or `NPM` and likewise for either of those tools or libraries they have nothing to do with the driver connections. So this would appear to be errors from different sources. In the context of a question, you really should be showing "code" which can reproduce the problem. At a most basic level, you really should verify that your "local machine" is able to contact all external hosts you reference.

Comment: @NeilLunn i am not saying it is all about the same error, CURL, NPM and MongoDb errors are separated errors but all was occur the same day.

Comment: We can't debug something we cannot see. If you want to ask a question here you need to provide a reproducible case. Everything else I've already said